# How can i remove a SKSpriteNode from parent, when the background is the same color as the sprite?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

Im making a game where the colour of a square will change every second and the background will also change colour every second, the user has to tap the square when it is the same colour as the background and the score will increase. But i cant work out how to do this.
This is the code i have so far:

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation MyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
            [self performSelector:@selector(backgrounds) withObject:nil ];
            [self performSelector:@selector(createSquare) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
            [self performSelector:@selector(createPSquare) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

        }
    return self;

}

-(void) backgrounds {
    SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"blueOutline"];
    background.name = @"blueOutline";
    background.size          = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
    background.position      = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:background];

    //meathod sequence at interval

}

-(void) createSquare {
    SKSpriteNode *blueSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"blue"];
    blueSprite.name = @"blueSprite";
    blueSprite.size          = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
    blueSprite.position      = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:blueSprite];

    //meathod sequence at interval

}

-(void) createPSquare {
    SKSpriteNode *pinkSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"pink"];
    pinkSprite.name = @"pinkSprite";
    pinkSprite.size          = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
    pinkSprite.position      = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)+10,CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:pinkSprite];

    //meathod sequence at interval

}



-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];


    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"blueSprite"]) {
        [node runAction:[SKAction removeFromParent]]; //Removes Sprite from parent
    }


    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"pinkSprite"]) {
        [node runAction:[SKAction removeFromParent]]; //Removes Sprite from parent
    }

}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```

Comment: [node runAction:[SKAction removeFromParent]] can be written as [node removeFromParent]

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thanks, i made the change, can u help with my main problem in anyway it would be a big help

Comment: you could (approximately) compare color values of sprite and background, or just tag the sprites via the userData dictionary

Comment: @LearnCocos2D i added this into my .h file: '@property(retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *userData;' but how do i use it in my main code above ^?

Comment: userData is a property of any node, that's what I meant: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userData

Comment: Also, if you only use the node's name-property as shown above you could match these rather than having to use the userData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you generalize the code that creates the squares and backgrounds to simplify adding more colors to your game. Here's an example of how to do that:

Define a type that identifies the type of sprite node to create

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger, SpriteType) {
    SpriteTypeBackground,
    SpriteTypeSquare
};
```

This method adds a square and a background to the scene each with a randomly selected color

```
- (void) addSquareAndBackground {
    _background = [self createSpriteWithType:SpriteTypeBackground];
    _square = [self createSpriteWithType:SpriteTypeSquare];
}
```

This removes the square and background from the scene

```
- (void) removeSquareAndBackground {
    [_background removeFromParent];
    [_square removeFromParent];
}
```

This creates either a square or a background sprite based on the specified type

```
-(SKSpriteNode *) createSpriteWithType:(SpriteType)type {
    // Select a color randomly
    NSString *colorName = [self randomColorName];
    SKSpriteNode *sprite;
    if (type == SpriteTypeBackground) {
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Outline",colorName];
        sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:name];
        sprite.name = name;
        sprite.size = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
    }
    else {
        sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:colorName];
        sprite.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Sprite",colorName];
        sprite.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
    }
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:sprite];

    return sprite;
}
```

Randomly select a color name

```
// Set the total number of colors here
#define kNumberOfColors     2

- (NSString *) randomColorName {
    NSString *colorName;
    switch (arc4random_uniform(kNumberOfColors)) {
        case 0:
            colorName = @"blue";
            break;
        case 1:
            colorName = @"pink";
            break;
        // Add more colors here
        default:
            break;
    }
    return colorName;
}
```

Add this to your touchesBegan method to test for a color match

```
    if (node == _square) {
        // Extract the color name from the node name
        NSArray *squareNameParts = [node.name componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet]];
        // Extract the color name from the node name
        NSArray *backgroundNameParts = [_background.name componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet]];
        // Compare if the colors match
        if ([backgroundNameParts[0] isEqualToString: squareNameParts[0]]) {
            NSLog(@"Score");
        }
    }
```

All that's left is to create an SKAction that calls addSquareAndBackground, waits for one second, and then calls removeSquareAndBackground. Lather, rinse, repeat!

**EDIT:** Add this above your @implementation MyScene statement:

```
@interface MyScene()

@property SKSpriteNode *background;
@property SKSpriteNode *square;

@end
```

Comment: -0x141E Using ur code i get this error, Use of undecleared identifier '_background' and this one, Use of undecleared identifier '_square'.

Comment: - (void) addSquareAndBackground {
    _background = [self createSpriteWithType:SpriteTypeBackground];
    _square = [self createSpriteWithType:SpriteTypeSquare];
} I think for some reason that this causing issues but im not to sure

Comment: I edited my answer. See changes in the EDIT section.